# Incompatible usage of \@ssect

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

In order to customize layout of chapter and section titles is is often suggested to do it in the following way:

```
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@startsection{chapter}{0}{\z@}{-2em}{6pt}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}}
```

My code has to work on machines with different TeX installations, and particularly on a machine with KOMA-Script v. 3.11, so this seems to be the only way to go (better KOMA-Script-specific options for redefining chapter layout etc. were intorduced in later versions).

However, after one of the recent updates I get the following warnings on other machines:

```
incompatible usage of \@ssect detected. You've used the KOMA-Script implementation of \@ssect from within a non compatible caller, that does not \scr@s@ct@@nn@m@ locally.
```

The problem seems to originate from usage of unnumbered chapters (including table of content title and glossary title).

Another problem poses usage of short section titles in combination with asterisk

The MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[%
final,% include images
twoside=semi
%]{scrartcl}
]{scrreprt}

%Layout redefinition of chapter, section, subsection and paragraph:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@startsection{chapter}{0}{\z@}{-2em}{6pt}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-1.5em}{6pt}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{1}{\z@}{-1.2em}{6pt}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{-2.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -0.2ex}{0.5ex \@plus 0.2ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%the first warning komes here (tableofcontents is defined as chapter*, which makes problems)
\tableofcontents

%Here everything is ok:
\chapter[First chapter - short title]{First chapter - long title - here is everything ok}
Some text

%The second warning is issued here:
\section*{First Section - long title - asterisk poses a problem}
Some further text

%Here there are two problems:
% - asterisk issues a warning
% - content of [..] is not recognized as the shot subsection title
\subsection*[First subsection - short title]{First subsection - long title - asterisk poses a problem}
Some more text

\end{document}
```

Is there any possibility to redefine sections in a way that everything works as desired?

Comment: If you are using the KOMA classes, it makes sense to use the facilities the class provides.

Comment: In know that several options for redefinig layout of sections were introduced in recent KOMA versions (such as \RedeclareSectionCommand)... Unfortunately they were introduced only in v. 3.15, so I cannot use them since I have to maintain compatibility to v. 3.11.

Comment: Supposedly, you should be able to access older versions of packages (and its documentation) at http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/, but it does not seem to be working currently. (It used to, but not today....) Anyway, surely class-based commands to reconfigure sectioning commands **long** antedate version 3.11. However, as to what they might be, I can't help: I don't really use the class myself.

Comment: I tried to solve the problem by using \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{-2\baselineskip}} and \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{} but this looks different on older and newer installations... The first looks good with older KOMA version and the second with the newer... Something seemes to have changed in KOMA inbetween. Any idea how to change the formatting in another way?

Comment: Maybe you can install a newer KOMA-Script version in your  texmfhome tree or in the texmflocal tree . Note that the starred version of the sectioning commands have no optional argument because there will be no TOC entry and no header entry for starred sectioning commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incopatibility was introduced by Koma-Script in v. 3.15. Since this version Koma-Script uses `\scr@startsection` instead of `\@startsection`.
The easiest way to eliminate the warning is thus to use `\scr@startsection` instead of `\@startsection` too and to provide a mapping for `\scr@startsection` for older Koma-Script versions. This is done by

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{scrbase}{2014/12/12}{% for newer versions: do nothing:
    %
}{% for older versions: use \@startsection instead of \scr@startsection:
    \def\scr@startsection{\@startsection}%
}%
\makeatother
```

The layout customisation commands can now use the `\scr@startsection` macro:

```
\makeatletter
% redefinition of sectioning commands using either \scr@startsection
% or \@startsection (depending on the Koma-Script version)
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\scr@startsection{chapter}{0}{\z@}{-2em}{6pt}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\section}{\scr@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-1.5em}{6pt}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\scr@startsection{subsection}{1}{\z@}{-1.2em}{6pt}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\scr@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{-2.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -0.2ex}{0.5ex \@plus 0.2ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}}
\makeatother
```

A differenciation between different Koma-Script versions as shown above may also be used in order to make use of the newest Koma-Script features such as `\RedeclareSectionCommand` without losing compatibility to older installations.